# HTTP download in IIS from network attached virtual directory

Tags: http, iis, download, virtual-directory

I'm having issues downloading the files(with non-standard extensions) from the mapped folder in IIS. "Everyone" group have full access to the remote folder and shared folder. I'm able to download txt, mp3 files but when I try to get f4v/mp4 files I'm getting 403: Forbidden errors.
On the IIS all the MIME types are added(If I have this folder locally I'm able to get all types of files).

Any ideas would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I run "Process Monitor" on the server and was able to see the process that was giving me "Access Denied". It is IIS Network Services. I checked the folder permissions once more and just in case added this account with the full access rights. Same 403 error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I needed to download flash files from the fileserver to our webserver via http protocol. I ended up installing IIS on the fileserver and configuring it with the proper MIME types so that it would be accessible from the webserver.